# what is the best settings for ios ipa genaration in xamarin forms,visual studio for small size?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, app-store, ipa

My `ipa` is of 35 mb now. I want to reduce the size. My current setting for build is as follows.

[image]

Comment: Checking project, and trying to remove only the libraries you don't use in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your resources (images), and try to compress them, using TinyPNG, for example.

In the Project Build Settings afaik there is nothing else for you to check.